Refresh tokens with Identity 8
I am currently developing the authentication feature of an app using ASP.NET 8 with Identity 8 also and Angular in the front. I set up a basic http only login and registration, I have a nice login persistance but am having trouble understanding how refresh token works in this context.
I have a refresh endpoint in my API but I can't access it, here's my frontend method for this :
const headers = { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' };  console.log("Refreshing..."); 
return this._httpClient.post(`${this.baseUrl}/refresh`, {}, { headers });}

and it should be sent whenever I am not authenticated via an auth guard :
if (accountService.currentUser()) {
    return of(true); // Allow access if user is authenticated
  } else {
    // Fetch the current authentication state
    return accountService.getAuthState().pipe(
      switchMap((authState) => {
        if (!authState.isAuthenticated) {
          // If not authenticated, try refreshing the token
          return accountService.refreshAccessToken().pipe(
            map(() => {
              // After refreshing, recheck the authentication state
              return true; // Token refresh was successful, allow access
            }),
            catchError(() => {
              // If refreshing fails, redirect to login
              router.navigate(['/account/login'], { queryParams: { returnUrl: state.url } });
              return of(false);
            })
          );
        } else {
          // If authenticated, allow access
          return of(true);
        }
      }),
      catchError(() => {
        // Handle any errors (e.g., network issues) and redirect to login
        router.navigate(['/account/login'], { queryParams: { returnUrl: state.url } });
        return of(false);
      })
    );
  }

In my back-end I don't have a huge config, I just tried to give a really short lifespan to my token to see the refresh request get sent via the network tab but I don't:
services.Configure<DataProtectionTokenProviderOptions>(options =>
{
   options.TokenLifespan = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(3);
});

Am I missing something ? Do you need to see more of my code?
I tried to add an empty {refreshToken: ''} to my request body but it doesn't work neither, tried to read the Mcrosoft doc...

The refresh token needs to be fetched before the previous token expires. Basically it's like saying "hey, I'm logged in but my session is about to expire. Give me a new token that will be valid for a little bit longer". In your case it seems you try fetching the refresh token when user is already not authenticated, which is bound to fail.

When you initially login, you should recieve refresh token along with access token. That is in case if you are not using cookie authentication but Token based authentication. The refresh token should be used to exchange for a new fresh access token. You can check access token expiration before making the api call. This way you can refresh if expired before making api call.
